# Set Focus to a Cocoa Window in Carbon App

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon, nswindow

I'm  trying to create a Cocoa Window within an otherwise Carbon Application (it's an OpenGL API that uses AGL.  Can't change it so don't comment on that).

Here's a code snippit:

```
WindowRef winref = static_cast<eq::AGLWindow*>(getOSWindow())->getCarbonWindow();
vc = [[SFAttachedViewController alloc] initWithConfig:config]; //loads from view nib
NSPoint buttonPoint = NSMakePoint(event.pointerButtonPress.x + [cocoaWrap frame].origin.x, [cocoaWrap frame].size.height - event.pointerButtonPress.y + [cocoaWrap frame].origin.y);
MAAttachedWindow *attachedWindow = [[MAAttachedWindow alloc] initWithView:[vc view] attachedToPoint:buttonPoint onSide:side atDistance:0.0f]; // some Matt Gemmell goodness!
```

And I try to show it with one of the following lines:

```
// A)
[NSApp runModalForWindow:[attachedWindow retain]]; // makes a white box
// B)
NSWindow *cocoaWrap = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithWindowRef:winref];
[cocoaWrap addChildWindow:attachedWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
// C)
[attachedWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
```

The window shows, but the focus is never given.  I can't edit any of the controls, and everything is grayed out.

help!?

I tried

```
HIViewRef viewRef;
HICocoaViewCreate([vc view], 0, &viewRef);
WindowRef attachedRef = (WindowRef)[attachedWindow windowRef];
SetKeyboardFocus(attachedRef, viewRef, kControlNoPart);
```

Thinking it might have been a Carbon/Cocoa thing, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you looked at this PDF yet? http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CarbonCocoaDoc/CarbonCocoaIntegration.pdf

Comment: Yes, which is why I had the NSApplicationLoad() call in my window init() method instead of in the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you call `NSApplicationLoad()` before calling Cocoa methods?

Comment: !?  I can't believe that was it.  I moved the call to the main thread instead of my rendering thread and voila!  working!  DERP *facepalm*

Comment: Good that it worked. In general, you shouldn't call any Cocoa UI methods from non-main threads. It's unfortunate but Cocoa uses a lot of main-thread-only constructs. e.g. You shouldn't call `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` from the secondary threads, etc. etc.